# Best free or paid video training series for learning Sharepoint 2016 from a Beginner/Intermediate level

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am a web developer who will be starting Sharepoint development and hasn't used Sharepoint much at all from an end user or developer side of things. I am looking for a training class to ramp up on it so I can be a better developer and make more informed architecture decisions. I found this course https://www.pluralsight.com/paths/sharepoint-2016-foundations. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna be straight forward with you and tell you that a training class will not take you far for SharePoint Development and are boring as heck. 
They will help you understand the basic structure and piece together basic ideas of lists/libraries and what not. This will not help you as developer.

Best bet is to tune to peoples blogs and Microsoft Office Dev community.

SharePoint Maven is great for you giving you a run down on what best practices are and he is pretty current. A lot of good content that deals with on-prem and sharepoint online/office365
https://sharepointmaven.com/blog-sharepoint-best-practices/

Marcs blog has recently gear itself more toward O365 bet there is a lot of good content if youre willing to dig.
https://sympmarc.com/

If youre stuck on SP16 on-prem I would stear clear of SPFx for now. They dont update it as reguarly as the SPFx for online, still using Node 8. That being said still check it out. But another alternative is using react/angular/vue apps inside content editors leveraging the SharePoint API. I do this whenever I can. SPjeff introduced me to this and I can't thank him enough. Check out more info
https://www.spjeff.com/?s=Angular

Lots of good stuff here.
https://veenstra.me.uk/

I dont know any good resources for navigating SharePoint designer. I just learned as I went along. Google will be your best friend in this situation.

If youre going to be doing online work. Check out the Microsoft Dev center.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/

Main points are to tune yourself in to SharePoint happenings and updates. The community for on-prem is shrinking so reach out to the blogs as much as possible. Like anything else you just have to dive in.